# 2d infinite world generation

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i am making a 2d game on Unity3d and i want to make an infinite world generation, i have created a gameobject called "chunk" where i will put another code for random spawning of other gameobjects it has a sprite render where i put my texture, for now, this is the code i have. it has nothing to do with infinite world generation but it places some "chunks" around the player

```
void Start () {

    rot = Quaternion.identity;

    x1 = (transform.position.x + 410); 
    y1 = (transform.position.y + 410); 
    x2 = (transform.position.x - 410); 
    y2 = (transform.position.y - 410); 
    x3 = (transform.position.x + 410); 
    y3 = (transform.position.y); 
    x4 = (transform.position.x);   
    y4 = (transform.position.y + 410);
    x5 = (transform.position.x - 410);
    y5 = (transform.position.y); 
    x6 = (transform.position.x);     
    y6 = (transform.position.y - 410); 
    x7 = (transform.position.x + 410);  
    y7 = (transform.position.y - 410);  
    x8 = (transform.position.x - 410);  
    y8 = (transform.position.y + 410); 

    Instantiate (chunk, transform.position, transform.rotation);
    Instantiate (chunk, new Vector3 (x1,y1,0), rot);
    Instantiate (chunk, new Vector3 (x2,y2,0), rot);
    Instantiate (chunk, new Vector3 (x3,y3,0), rot);
    Instantiate (chunk, new Vector3 (x4,y4,0), rot);
    Instantiate (chunk, new Vector3 (x5,y5,0), rot);
    Instantiate (chunk, new Vector3 (x6,y6,0), rot);
    Instantiate (chunk, new Vector3 (x7,y7,0), rot);
    Instantiate (chunk, new Vector3 (x8,y8,0), rot);
}
```

my question is, how can i make an infinite world generation?

Comment: if anybody know how i can create an infinite world generation, im going to put it in the main question

Comment: it's difficult to explain, hope that somebody understand what i mean XD, i know it isn't simple to do something like this.

Comment: Have you had a look at the PCG wiki here: http://pcg.wikidot.com/? There are a few articles there that cover world generation that might give you some ideas.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't any one way of doing this, so the answers you're going to receive such as this one are going to be more conceptual than specific pieces of code. Anyway...

You could consider having a 2D array of the chunks, and create a new chunk object on the end of the far most right one whilst destroying the one on the far most left when the player entered a new chunk from the left. Equally the reverse could be said for when entering a new chunk from the right, however this method wouldn't offer you too much chunk management.

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into Perlin Noise.
You ought to be able to consistently generate the same value based on coordinates at any location, thus giving you an "infinite" world.